# Rails metaprogramming 10 x 0 Me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying do dynamically validate an object.

On my app, a user can create questions that will be part of a form, and each question can have 
validations.

So, I post this form, and pass the param to the following class:

```
require 'ostruct'
class QuestionResponse < OpenStruct
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming
  extend  ActiveModel::Callbacks

  def fields
    @table.keys
  end

  def add_validators
    stored_questions = AdmissionForm.find(self.form_id).questions.all
    questions = fields.select{|f| f.to_s[0]=="q"}
    questions.each do |question_param|
      question = stored_questions.select{|f| f["id"] == question_param.to_s.gsub("q_","").to_i}.first
      unless question.validations.empty?
        validations = "validates :#{question_param} , #{question.validations.join(",")}"
        self.class.instance_eval validations
      end
    end

  end

  def initialize(*args)
    super
    add_validators if self.fields.any?
  end
  def persisted? ; false ; end;
end
```

It almost works.
My problem is that subsequent form posts, concatenate ActiveModel::Errors

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000004432520
 @base=#<QuestionResponse q_7="", q_6="", form_id="1">,
 @messages=
  {:q_7=>["cant be blank", "cant be blank"],
   :q_6=>["cant be blank", "cant be blank"]}>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

`add_validators` gets called on every instance of `QuestionResponse`, which adds validations to the class of `QuestionResponse`. Each new instance adds it's own validations to the class, but you still have the ones added by other (previously created) instances.

Comment: Doesn't self.class.instance_eval adds only to the current instance? If not is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: You are calling instance_eval on QuestionResponse, so you end up modifying the QuestionResponse class